# I'm trying to send whtasapp message using C# console application but I am getting error like

Tags: c#, .net, twilio, whatsapp

I want to send WhatsApp messages using C# and Twilio.
I am getting an arror at `MessageResource.Create`: Connection Error: POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC0a30xxxxxxxx/Messages.json

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string accountSid = "xxxxx";
            string authToken = "xxxxxx";
            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
            var message = MessageResource.Create(
                from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+14155238886"),
                body: "Hello there!",
                to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+91xxxxxxxxxx")
            );
            Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code and see which line is throwing the exception? Did you observe the exception? What is the Message property of the exception? You should use try catch block to catch the exception and print the exception details in the Console. Share the exception details in the question. That will help us to understand more about the issue and so in solving it faster.

Comment: Documentations could help 
-https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/quickstart/csharp
-https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-set-up-your-csharp-and-asp-net-mvc-development-environment

Comment: I have updated the error, please can someone solve this

Comment: Unfortunately, that error doesn't say much. Are you sure that's the only error you see? You should be seeing an exception in the output with a stacktrace.

Comment: Make sure you opted into the Twilio Sandbox number from the phone number you're trying to send messages to. This is for development only, so you won't need this in production, but you will need to do this to test. @malisasmaz shared docs that include instructions on how to do that.